# Replace content of appended div in Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am building a web app image gallery using FancyBox. Right now I am appending
a custom div to the popup (image) where I need to place image specific links.

How can I replace the content of the tools div everytime I click next to another image?
Or better yet, is it possible to append this div from inside the popup?

This is my code:

```
$(".iframe").fancybox ({

afterShow: function () {

var toolbar = '<div id="tools">LINKS COME HERE</div>';

$(".fancybox-inner").append(toolbar);

},

maxWidth    : 1200,

maxHeight   : 550,

width       : '90%',

height      : '90%',

autoSize    : false,

closeBtn  : false,

openEffect  : 'none',

closeEffect : 'none',

nextEffect: 'none',

prevEffect: 'none',

padding: 0,

scrolling: 'no'

});
```

Comment: so, does it work? or do you have any further questions? I think I provideded a well documented answer so a bit of feedback would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can create the content (of the `div` to be appended) for each image in a separated (hidden) section of your document like

```
<div id="appendContent" style="display: none;">
 <div>content with links to be appended to the first image</div>
 <div>content with links to be appended to the second image</div>
 <div>content with links to be appended to the third image</div>
 ... etc.
</div>
```

The structure above assumes that you should have an equal number of images for each `div` in your gallery like:

```
<a href="image01.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">image 01</a>
<a href="image02.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">image 02</a>
<a href="image03.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery">image 03</a>
etc.
```

Additionally you can create a css selector for the appended `div` within your css stylesheet rather than using the `.css()` method (as suggested in your other question) like:

```
#tools {
 position: absolute; 
 z-index: 99999;
 bottom: 0px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 background: #fff;
 width: 100%;
}
```

...or the style settings you need.

Then pull the content of each `div` and append it dynamically to the corresponding image while navigating through the gallery.

using the `afterShow` callback option, you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  afterShow: function(){
   var toolbar = "<div id='tools'>" + $("#appendContent div").eq(this.index).html() + "</div>";
   $(".fancybox-inner").append(toolbar);
  }
 }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

Comment: Would be cool if I could show / hide this div when hovering the image so that I can access links in it. How can I do that?