# Multi line title with dynamic content on Fancybox 2?

Tags: fancybox, title, multiline

I'm currently using fancybox 2 on a php generated image gallery.
I'd like to have a multi line "title" in the fancy box.

By default, the image title shown on the fancy box window is the value of the title parameter.

I would like to have the title followed by a description like this :

Title
Description

So, Instead of reading the title value, I would like Fancybox reading the content of a custom and invisible div like this :

[title] 
 [description]

(of course, [title] and [description] are php generated variables)

I don't know much about js and jquery, so I don't know how to modify this.

If you know how to do that, it would be helpful. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there are two different ways of how you could do it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9813775/1055987

...or you may consider my "*a la*" facebook way:

http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxALAfacebook_26Mar12.html