# How to rename fancybox title attribute rename to fancytitle

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, fancybox

If youd like to change the title attribute used in fancybox v2 to fancyboxtitle, this is how.  The reason I needed to change it is because I need to use the regular title attribute for slightly different tooltip/alt text.

```
                if (isQuery(element)) {
                    obj = {
                        href    : element.data('fancybox-href') || element.attr('href'),
                        title   : element.data('fancybox-title') || element.attr('fancytitle'), /* Changed to fancy-title*/
                        isDom   : true,
                        element : element
                    };
```

Comment: Figured it out.  Didn't need to rename the first title.

Comment: if your need a different element for fancybox title check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/9813775/1055987